# How can I show the console for a Windows GUI application only when it is started from the console?

Tags: windows, powershell, rust, console, exe

I have a graphical application. When I open the .exe it should not show a console. When I run it from the console I want console output.

At first, I always got a console window in addition to the application window. I found this annoying, so I set [`#![windows_subsystem = "windows"]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/reference/runtime.html#the-windows_subsystem-attribute). Now the console window is gone when I start the application, but also I don't get any logs when running it from console.

How can I get both?

Comment: See also [How would i run a Rust program without a window only when it's in release mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68238935/155423); [How to make a program that does not display the console window?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29763647/155423)

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I have a hidden console when using windows_subsystem?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64346513/155423)